# Lambda function returns timeout even after getting the response

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have a java based `AWS` lambda function which gets called through API Gateway about 10-15 times a day which is very less as per me.

The Lambda config has a memory of 1024 MB and timeout limit of 15 sec. 
But from the past week or so, the lambda function times out even after getting the response. 
And this occurrence is not uniform. It's sporadic. And eventually executes normally after some time.

We have tried optimizing the code and it shouldn't take more than ~8 sec to execute. 
Hoping to find a solution for this. Let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks in advance.

The issue is similar to this question: [AWS Lambda function timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776264/aws-lambda-function-timing-out)

The only difference being the tech used: The above question used nodeJS and we use Java

--Update: 
One more thing I have noticed is when the `API` is hit after being idle for long, it takes more time to get executed than when you hit it consecutively. 
I checked the logs and when I hit it for the 1st time it took roughly 7-8 secs to execute and just after 2 consecutive hits the response time reduced to a mere 2 secs.. Very strange...

Comment: the time that you are telling is just for the time taken by Lambda expression or by your whole  API?

Comment: @NikhilPareek Just the lambda.. Not the API

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having problems related to warmup on the lambda/api gateway.
There were already some of people [complaining about this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=226136).

There are some workarounds you could do to keep the lambda warm, [for example triggers](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0).

> I checked the logs and when I hit it for the 1st time it took roughly 7-8 secs to execute and just after 2 consecutive hits the response time reduced to a mere 2 secs.. Very strange...

This is because you have a warm lambda, therefore it doesn't need to create a new one.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case pertaining to warm up on the lambda functions. However, my 1st issue: 
_But from the past week or so, the lambda function times out even after getting the response. And this occurrence is not uniform. It's sporadic. And eventually executes normally after sometime._
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: tbh, it's a weird scenario, did you noticed the time when the timeout is logged? also what's the memory you have selected for the lambda?

Comment: The memory selected is 1024 MB. The timeout I checked from the logs in cloud watch. Basically when the request is sent to a lambda function, there is a start request which is logged. And I have added loggers at the end of execution to check if the response is received or not. And this logger gets logged in Cloud watch. But right after this happens, the request is timed out. The timeout set is 15 sec

Comment: Seems a weird case, the lambda shouldn't give timeout if the response is sent

Comment: Exactly.. That was my thought as well.. But you can see this is a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40776264/aws-lambda-function-timing-out where there's a snapshot given as well